# py.test parameterized fixtures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am currently working on some unit test cases and test fixtures using [py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html)

I have some code that does this:

```
# my py.test file
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1():
    f = open("file_one.txt", 'rb')
    f_str = f.read()
    yield f_str
    f.close()

def test_function_1(fixture_1):
    assert fixture_1.startswith("some_test_data") # example test
```

This is all good and works fine.

Now let's say I write another test function that works with input stored in another file (let's say `file_two.txt` and my function is like this:

```
# in same py file as above
def test_function_2(fixture_1):
     #some test with data from file_two.txt
     assert something_for_fun
```

In the `test_function_2` above, i want to `fixture_1` to do the same operations as before but on `file_two.txt` instead of  `file_one.txt`.

**EDIT** : I also played with [parametrizing fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures) but that invokes my test_function_* as many times as the number of arguments to the fixture, which doesn't work since the test_functions are specific to the input from a file.

I read about the the [request](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#request-context) fixture, but not sure how to use it to inspect the context of a test function.

If anyone has that figured out, please let me know. Meanwhile I will post as soon as i get it working!

**EDIT 2:** I also know about `inspect` and `introspect` BUT i am looking for a cleaner way to do this, preferably by using some `pytest` magic~

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parametrize the fixture from test and read the passed parameter via `request.param`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1(request):
    filename = request.param
    with open(filename) as f:
        f_str = f.read()
    yield f_str


@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_1', ['file_one.txt'], indirect=True)
def test_function_1(fixture_1):
    assert fixture_1.startswith("some_test_data") # example test


@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_1', ['file_two.txt'], indirect=True)
def test_function_2(fixture_1):
    assert something_for_fun
```

Test run should yield:

```
test_module.py::test_function_1[file_one.txt] PASSED
test_module.py::test_function_2[file_two.txt] PASSED
```

You can also set up a default fixture value for the filename and parametrize on demand:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1(request):
    filename = getattr(request, 'param', 'file_one.txt')
    with open(filename) as f:
        f_str = f.read()
    yield f_str


def test_function_1(fixture_1):
    assert fixture_1.startswith("some_test_data") # example test


@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_1', ['file_two.txt'], indirect=True)
def test_function_2(fixture_1):
    assert fixture_1.startswith('bar')
```

Now `test_function_1` stays unparametrized:

```
test_module.py::test_function_1 PASSED
test_module.py::test_function_2[file_two.txt] PASSED
```

Comment: Glad I could help!